# Wifi 'Connect' button greyed out

Tags: networking, xubuntu, password

After changing my password in my University's system I am no longer able to connect to the University's Wifi. I have no problem connecting to other networks and no problem connecting to the Uni's wifi under windows (dual-boot) or iphone with my new password.

I've made sure that I kept all the settings the same (see screenshot), but the 'Connect' button remains greyed out, even when I try to enter more characters in the password field. I also tried deleting the network profile and adding it again. I can't add it again since the button is greyed out.

I found other threads dealing with a greyed out 'connect' button but not when the password was changed.

I am running Xubuntu 16.04. I appreciate any help!

[image: network settings]

Comment: Are you sure you don't need a CA certificate?

Comment: It turns out I do. I was not expecting that to be the problem. I was not expecting Network Manager to know whether I needed one and grey out the connect button if I didn't enter one. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! @edwinksl

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `etc/ssl/certs/Addtrust_External_Root.pem` certificate solved the problem!