# WPA2 Enterprise EAP-TLS connect button grayed out

Tags: networking, wireless, hostapd, wpa2

I'm trying to connect to a WPA2 Enterprise wifi that I've setup. I can successfully connect using PEAP using just username and password, but when I try to connect with 802.1x certificates only (EAP-TLS), the connect button is grayed out and whatever I do it doesn't become clickable. Note that the password is definitely correct and I don't know why it's colored as red (Ubuntu 18.04).

**Question 1:** 
Shouldn't it allow me to connect (even with false information)? Can I deduce it's a hardware issue that it doesn't give me the connect button regardless of the parameters?

I already found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/821930/wifi-connect-button-greyed-out), but my issue has a different source since I have the CA certificate:

[image]

**Question 2:** Is it possible that my hostapd configuration is wrong and therefore it doesn't even allow me to try EAP-TLS?

This is my hostapd file on the access point (please keep in mind that with this exact configuration I'm still able to successfully connect with PEAP):

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=******
hw_mode=g
channel=7
ieee8021x=1
auth_algs=1
eap_server=0
eapol_key_index_workaround=0 

wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
auth_server_addr=127.0.0.1
auth_server_port=1812
auth_server_shared_secret=testing123
acct_server_addr=127.0.0.1
acct_server_port=1813
acct_server_shared_secret=testing123
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

EDIT: 
All the certificates are created/signed manually.

Comment: @pomsky just added to the question. It's 18.04 . Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related, there is an issue with WPA/WPA2 Enterprise connection on Ubuntu 18.04: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046810/cannot-downgrade-wpa-supplicant-to-fix-wi-fi-connection-to-a-corporate-network